# expo sdk 40 metro.config.js "Expected 'fromDir' to be 'string', got 'undefined' "

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I’m on a monorepo with yarn workspace and I’m also using react-native-svg-transformer.
I have updated the sdk to the sdk 40 and I have this error in the metro.config.js :
[image]

and there is my metro.config.js :

```
const { createMetroConfiguration } = require('expo-yarn-workspaces');
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');
const configuration = createMetroConfiguration(__dirname);
module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
    },
    resolver: {
      ...configuration.resolver,
      assetExts: configuration.resolver.assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
      // NOTE: using native entrypoint because bug in metro https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/485
      resolverMainFields: ['native', 'module', 'browser', 'main'],
    },
  };
})();
```

If you have any idea ?

Comment: Hey there E.D! How did you resolve this? Did you handle with that new library you've mentioned down here?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess yes as I was able to indicate in the comment below ;)

Comment: Hey I got it solved somehow @E.D

Answer (score 16):

Add the `__dirname` param in `await getDefaultConfig()` so it should be `await getDefaultConfig(__dirname)`

It is required as per [docs](https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro/#adding-more-file-extensions-to--assetexts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Andrei Trinidad ;)
Now I use https://github.com/gregberge/svgr no custom config needed